# Drawing an absolute line in a window in C#

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, graphics, controls

I have an application on windows with multiline text field on it. I need a way to draw lines on that text field, so you could see both, the letters typed and those lines. I need to do this with C#, but I can use .dll's written in C++.

I've heard something about subclassing where I could overtake render function from a window and adjust something to it, how do I do that with C#?

Or maybe there are simplier ways than that? Please share.

Comment: Have you already tried to do something?

Comment: TextBox, not "text field".  No, it doesn't support custom painting.  Hacking the WM_PAINT message handler is easy enough by overriding WndProc() but it will lead to disappointment.  TextBox breaks the rules and paints without WM_PAINT.  A crime that dates from the late 1980s when Windows had to run on a 386SUX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET Framework, you may use WPF and write user control with **Canvas** and **TextBox** overlaying - and then make such operations with **Dependency Properties** tracking

Comment: That was ridiculously easy, I don't know what I would have done without WPF.